# Javascript onkeyup / onblur

Tags: javascript

I have this sign up form with different types of fields. The following code is for the name field, where the border and some icon of the field are turned green when the name contain more than 3 characters. My question is how should I modify the code for a dropdown field ( select and option ) to turn the field's border and the icon green ? I've tried hardly to do this but I couldn't.

Surname field:

```
surname.onkeyup = function() {
  // Validate length
  if(surname.value.length >= 3) {
  // GREEN
     document.getElementById("surname").style.border = "1px solid #7ed321";
     document.getElementById("surname").style.color = "#7ed321";
     document.getElementById("icon-surname").style.color = "#7ed321";
     surname.onblur = function() {
         document.getElementById("surname").style.border = "1px solid #7ed321";
         document.getElementById("surname").style.color = "#000000";
         document.getElementById("icon-surname").style.color = "#7ed321";
     }
  } else {
  // RED
     document.getElementById("surname").style.border = "1px solid #bc0909";
     document.getElementById("surname").style.color = "#bc0909";
     document.getElementById("icon-surname").style.color = "#bc0909";
     surname.onblur = function() {
         document.getElementById("surname").style.border = "1px solid #bc0909";
         document.getElementById("surname").style.color = "#000000";
         document.getElementById("icon-surname").style.color = "#bc0909";
     }
   } 
 }
```

County field (dropdown):

```
     <select class="judet" id="judet">
        <option disabled selected value> -- Selectați Județul -- </option>
        <option value="Alba">Alba</option>
        <option value="Arad">Arad</option>
        <option value="Arges">Argeș</option>
        <option value="Bacau">Bacău</option>
        <option value="Bihor">Bihor</option>
     </select>
     <div class="input-icon"><i id="icon-judet" class="fas fa-map-marker"></i></div>


    judet.onkeyup = function() {
        var judet = document.getElementById("judet").selectedIndex;
        if(judet) {
           // GREEN
           document.getElementById("judet").style.border = "1px solid #7ed321";
           document.getElementById("icon-judet").style.color = "#7ed321";
           judet.onblur = function() {
               document.getElementById("judet").style.border = "1px solid #7ed321";
               document.getElementById("judet").style.color = "#000000";
               document.getElementById("icon-judet").style.color = "#7ed321";
           }
        } else {
           // RED
           document.getElementById("judet").style.border = "1px solid #bc0909";
           document.getElementById("icon-judet").style.color = "#bc0909";
           judet.onblur = function() {
               document.getElementById("judet").style.border = "1px solid #bc0909";
               document.getElementById("judet").style.color = "#000000";
               document.getElementById("icon-judet").style.color = "#bc0909";
           }
        } 
    }
```

Why the second doesn't work and doesn't change it's color and the first one is working ? Thank you in advice!

Comment: Are you using your keyboard to select an option? If you're using a mouse, `onkeyup` isn't going to fire...

Comment: Please [edit] your question with how your code and your HTML are connected. See [mcve]. Feel free to use the Stack Snippets (icon like `<>`) to create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one problem here. But in keeping with SO standards I am going to answer the question you asked.

It appears from the code snippet you provided, **the reason the second one doesn't work** is because the variable `judet` is undefined at the time it is used to assign the `onkeyup` event handler. As they are above, `judet` doesn't exist on the first line, so the event handler is never assigned.

To fix this, it appears you need to reverse the order of these two lines of code:

```
judet.onkeyup = function() {
    var judet = document.getElementById("judet").selectedIndex;
```

Like so:

```
var judet = document.getElementById("judet").selectedIndex;
judet.change = function() {
```

`judet` is recognized and will work properly.

======

Unrelated to your question, assigning and event handler to DOM property is troublesome. Please change the event handler to the `<select>` element. Secondly, the appropriate event handler to use on a `<select>` element is the `change` event. This will capture both keyboard and pointer events appropriately. For you consideration.

Comment: ... `onkeyup` on a number (`selectedIndex`)?

Comment: Well right - that seems to be a different problem. I'll address in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Umm... I appreciate the mention, but I didn't say anything about assigning event handlers in an HTML attribute, and neither did the OP. I merely mentioned that an `onkeyup` won't fire unless, well, a key goes down and then up. I think we need more from the OP before a correct answer can be written.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I've modified my answer to address the specific question asked. If the question changes I'll address the new question at that time.

Comment: I have made the changes but it still doesn't work. I appreciate your help, guys! I'll keep trying. Thank you!